Can you add new conditions for notifications sounds in Windows?
Let me be clear; I don't want to change the actual sound when I disconnect a device or something. I want to be able to add a new condition that Windows can play a sound for.
Mainly, I'd like Windows to make a noise whenever there's no internet connection. Whenever this icon pops up: Icon , I'd like to hear a sound. Surely there has to be a way within Windows to add more conditions for sounds?


Surely there has to be a way within Windows to add more conditions for sounds?

Windows sounds are not based on conditions. There is no central facility that plays sounds "when X or Y happens" – only the list of "system sounds" is central, but other than that, different programs and pieces of code handle everything. For example, there's a specific piece of code in Explorer that reacts to "device hotplug" events and 'manually' plays the respective sound. If a notification is shown, then the "desktop notification" code also plays the sound.
So the only way to add a sound for "network interface down" is to have an actual program that monitors network interfaces and plays a sound – maybe something with Autohotkey, maybe a scheduled task.
